# How to use the %%globaltimer register in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

An answer to this question suggests using the `%%globaltimer` register to measure elapsed time in a CUDA kernel. I decided to try it out:

```cpp
#define NS_PER_S 1000000000

__global__ void sleepKernel() {
    uint64_t start, end;
    uint64_t sleepTime = 5 * NS_PER_S;     // Sleep for 5 seconds

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        // Record start time
        asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%globaltimer;" : "=l"(start));

        // Sleep for 5 seconds
        __nanosleep(sleepTime);

        // Record end time
        asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%globaltimer;" : "=l"(end));

        // Calculate and print the elapsed time in nanoseconds and milliseconds
        uint64_t elapsedNs = end - start;
        double elapsedMs = (double)elapsedNs / 1000000.0;
        printf("Slept for %llu nanoseconds (%.3f milliseconds)\n", elapsedNs, elapsedMs);
    }
}
```

But, when I call this kernel, the outputs are things like:

```
slept for 73728 nanoseconds (0.074 milliseconds)
slept for 471040 nanoseconds (0.471 milliseconds)
```

both of which are much smaller than 5 seconds. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** doing:

```
    uint64_t sleepTime = 5 * (uint64_t)NS_PER_S;     // Sleep for 5 seconds
```

helped a bit (prevent integer overflow), but it wasn't sufficient

Comment: Are you asking, why __nanosleep or why globaltimer does not work as intended? Does it work for shorter times, e.g. 10us? Please move the printf out of the kernel into host code. It messes all kind of things (timing, memory, ...) up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the source of the confusion here is due to the usage of `__nanosleep()`. If we start by reading the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#nanosleep-function) and the relevant [ptx documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#miscellaneous-instructions-nanosleep) we will observe noteworthy things:

1. the argument passed to it is `unsigned`, which is a 32-bit quantity.  There is no way to closely express 5 seconds when the quantum is a nanosecond, and the argument is `unsigned`. Passing a 64-bit value isn't formally available, and doesn't change this. But wait, there's more.
2. the word "approximately" is used.  In the PTX doc we see that the function it is based on actually offers a delay in the range of zero(!) to twice the value you specify.  That's probably not what most people expect in a delay function.
3. at least in PTX, the function cannot be used to provide a delay of more than 1 millisecond.  Nowhere close to 5 seconds, nor close to what you can ask for in a 32-bit quantity.

A bit of [compilation and PTX analysis](https://godbolt.org/z/d5zzWccc3) will show you that the CUDA C++ intrinsic is using the PTX function, more or less directly, so it has the same curious characteristics.  I won't be able to respond to "why is it that way?" questions or "what is it useful for?" questions.

Taking that into account, since the title of your question at least is related to `globaltimer`, not `__nanosleep`, we can readily verify that `globaltimer` seems to work roughly as advertised:

```
# cat t118.cu
#define NS_PER_S 1000000000ULL
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start=0){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

__global__ void sleepKernel(uint64_t sleepTime = 5 *NS_PER_S) {
    uint64_t start, end;

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        // Record start time
        asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%globaltimer;" : "=l"(start));
        end = start;
        // Sleep for 5 seconds
        while (end < (start + sleepTime))
          asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%globaltimer;" : "=l"(end));
    }
}


int main(){
        sleepKernel<<<1,1>>>(100);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        unsigned long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
        sleepKernel<<<1,1>>>();
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        dt = dtime_usec(dt);
        std::cout << "elapsed: " << dt << "us" << std::endl;
}
# nvcc -o t118 t118.cu -arch=sm_89
# ./t118
elapsed: 5000023us
#
```

Notes:

1. I don't normally recommend PTX analysis for understanding.  However it is useful and sufficient here, to show the connection between the CUDA C++ intrinsic and the underlying PTX function that we can infer behavior from.
2. I've already filed an internal bug (3608779) at NVIDIA to have the documentation for the CUDA C++ intrinsic (`__nanosleep()`) updated to better reflect what is discoverable in the PTX doc.
3. The first kernel launch is a "warm-up" to absorb various CUDA start-up overheads.  If you want to see what that means, just remove it.